# See what is getting garbage collected

Tags: java, android

I am developing and optimizing an Android application.

The Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT) is great to see what objects aren't being garbage collected, and to patch up those memory leaks but what I want to know is the opposite:

**How can I see what objects ARE being garbage collected?**
I'm not interested in what is being retained.

Why would I want to do that? Well, I am running something in an infinite loop in a background thread. Stuff happens very fast, and garbage collection is being called often.
I don't see any memory leaks, but perhaps because a lot of stuff is happening, Android decides that a ***few hundred commands have been called... now would be a good time to run the garbage collection!***

It could be collecting something normal like some Strings or ints that have gone out of scope, for example.

For my goals, I would like to try to prevent as much garbage collection lag as possible by reducing the number of objects I'm creating, but knowing what gets collected so often would be useful. I can then try to prevent the often collected objects from being created in the first place, or retain these objects so that they can be reused without being recreated often.

Comment: It is probably easier to determine that by looking at the loop code.  In these situations, the life time and visibility of objects is critical. Perhaps post relevant code, especially showing where the declaration, initialisation and assignment of variables takes place.  Aiming to use the stack rather than the heap is also a worthy aim since the stack is simply discarded when the scope changes.  Also, using StringBuilder rather than string, being careful about boxing/unboxing and so on.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, but that is valid and useful advice. I've been doing some tests, and the stuff being garbage collected, however, does not appear to be within my own code, but rather, within another library or within the Android system itself, so it would be useful to know what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible because the JVM generally does not know (or care) what objects are removed during GC.

In fact, GC doesn't really "collect" the garbage. It actually works in the opposite way, determining which objects are live by following references, starting from the heap roots (e.g. local references owned by threads).

Only objects encountered during this heap walk are retained. Anything that isn't seen during the walk is ignored and not copied/compacted. These leftovers are the garbage that is effectively "collected", but the JVM does not know or care what those objects are.